# How to find the required tables of a BAPI function?

Tags: abap, bapi, function-module

I'm new to SAP and studying calling some predefined BAPI function using JAVA. I have a question. I open the function BAPI_QUOTATION_CREATEFROMDATA2 in SE37. In it, I found import and tables. The import is the parameters I need when calling this function, but in tables, there are about 12 tables and structures, how do I know which is the minimum requirement to call the function? Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: The minimum requirement to call the function is not only technical: some "technically-optional" parameters may be required. Do you mean "required tables" or "required parameters"? (cf Optional column for parameters in Import, Changing and Tables tabs). The parameters of type "Tables" are more or less obsolete nowadays (by using xrfc). Note that nothing prevents the Import or Changing parameters from being tables too, although it's extremely rare for BAPIs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please see the optional column, highlighted in the image below. The tables that are optional are checked. Tables that do not have 'Optional' checked are required. You can see from the image that 'QUOTATION_PARTNERS' is the required table.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. one more question. i want to create a vendor using function BAPI_VENDOR_CREATE,but in function viewer both the import and tables are empty, do u know why?

Comment: @kkluo Have you populated the tables? When you click execute, it takes you to "test function module: initial screen" - there you can edit the tables and import parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is a BAPI, it is a generally released function module by SAP and therefore better documented than just any other function module. Most BAPI's have good documentation that you can access in SE37 by clicking on Function Module Documentation.

Unfortunately for BAPI_QUOTATION_CREATEFROMDATA2 is looks like the developer was lazy and copy pasted it from an order creation BAPI since it mentions:

```
 Notes
 1. Required entries: ORDER_HEADER_IN : DOC_TYPE     Sales document type
                    SALES_ORG    Sales organization
                    DISTR_CHAN   Distribution channel
                    DIVISION     Division ORDER_PARTNERS..: PARTN_ROLE   Partner role, Sold.to party
                    PARTN_NUMB   Customer number ORDER_ITEMS_IN..: MATERIAL     Material number
```

Luckily the documentation for the parameter itself is a bit betterL

The minimum requirement is that the sold-to party is entered at header level. Additional partner functions can then be automatically determined.